# Centos 6 interactive ssh disconnects immediately after authenticating, but able to execute noninteractive commands fine

Tags: centos, ssh

I have a server that is authenticating and printing the lastlogin banner just fine, but then immediately disconnects. However, I am able to execute noninteractive commands without issue (for example, I can `ssh me@myserver.com ls` and see the homedir).

I've already done some reading and research and tried numerous things.

- I remote rebooted the machine
- `ssh -t me@myserver.com /bin/sh` (and `/bin/tcsh` and `/bin/bash` and `/bin/csh`) all behave similarly to `ssh me@myserver.com`
- I've looked at the .bashrc and .bash_profile in my home directory and they look fine.
- I've created a second account (I can run `adduser` via ssh) and the new account experiences the same problem.
- I've checked /var/log/messages, /var/log/secure, etc, and there is nothing that looks obviously wrong to me.
- I've tried sshing with verbosity, even at max verbosity it looks like the connection just closes without cause.
- /etc/passwd looks fine and points to a valid existing shell for the user.
- home directory exists
- network connectivity (including DNS resolution) seems fine
- load on the machine looks light, there are no unexpected processes listed, memory is fine, and disk has plenty of free space.

I do not have console access to this machine, so I'm hesitant to try modifying config files that might lead to a further loss of connectivity (i.e. if I break /etc/ssh/sshd_config, there would be no way to recover).

There's no obvious indication of when this problem occurred, other than a note that the provider did an OS patch about a month ago. I do have a ticket with the provider, but I am not confident.

Update: Not using the `-t` option with ssh and executing a shell did sort of work, for example `ssh me@myserver.com /bin/bash`. There's no last login, no banner, no prompt, but it does accept input from stdin and run commands.

Update: Another interesting tidbit. Tried the following on a known-good server and it lists a /dev/pts/ device, but on this server we get "not a tty":

```
ssh -t me@myserver.com tty                       
me@myserver.com's password: 
not a tty
```

Comment: Run sshd at max verbosity on the server, and check the logs it generates.

Comment: Check if the home defined in /etc/passwd have ends with /. It shouldn't.

Comment: could be the various ~/.bash* scripts which behave differently when there's a tty (btw, run `bash -i` instead of just bash, you get the usual prompt (but still no job, ctrl-c, ctrl-z etc. though the ctrl-x are still applied on the ssh command rather than the shell)

Comment: @JoãoAlves no trailing slashes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton is there any way to restart the server without first editing the config files? I'm concerned about damaging the config file, then the ssh daemon can't start, and there's no way to get back in to fix it.

Comment: @A.B Thanks, "bash -i" does give me a prompt but the ctrl characters not working right is a real pain.

Comment: Just start a second copy on some other port, e.g. `/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -p 2200` and connect to that alternate port.

Comment: Support at the hosting company resolved the problem before I could diagnose further. They didn't say how.